# Rewrite a C++ vector to java vector

Tags: java, c++

My task is to migrate a code from C++ to Java.

In the C++ there is a vector called vector1 with the following code:

```cpp
vector1[0].insert(vector1[0].begin(), to_string(i+1)[0]);
```

How should I write this code to work in java?

Comment: Vector of what? From the code example it looks like it's a vector of arrays.

Comment: The closer match in Java to std::vector is java.util.ArrayList, not Vector.

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippets i can guess it a vector of vector of characters because you add a chat from the string, so the code in java will be like this

```java
int i = 1;
Vector<Vector<Character>> vector1 = new Vector<>();
vector1.add(new Vector<>());
vector1.get(0).add(0, String.valueOf(i + 1).charAt(0));
System.out.println(vector1);
```

If you know the number of vectors it can be Array of vectors of characters like this

```java
int i = 1;
Vector[] vector1 = new Vector[10];
vector1[0] = new Vector<Character>();
vector1[0].add(0, String.valueOf(i + 1).charAt(0));
```